# Trying to add styles to tables in CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to add some style to my second table.

I try to access the second table in CSS by `table:nth-of-type(2)`. And then I try to manipulate the row sizes like this:

```
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:first-child{
    width="4%";

} 
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-child(2){
    width="91%";

} 
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-child(3){
    width="5%";

}
```

The HTML code for the second table looks like this:

```
<table class="ex2fixed">
    <tr>
        <td>Fighter</td>
        <td>Wins</td>
        <td>Loses</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ian McGregor</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is wrong with my code since the styles doesn't apply to my site...

Comment: can't you give a class to the second table and reach it in css with the class? .ex2fixed{width:"91%";}

Comment: I want specific width for each row. wouldn't that method require me to add a class to every row then?

Comment: What do you mean  a specific width for each row? Are you sure you need a table? Or do you mean a specific width for each column?

Comment: Sorry for each column. yeah I need a table.

Answer (score 4):

Th equal sign `=` is not valid in CSS.

You have to use the `:` sign to separate key and value.

Also quotes are useless is CSS

So `width="91%";` is `width: 91%;`

Comment: It is not it :/. still doesnt work. even tried to add "table.ex2fixed" before every statement that starts with "table:nth-of-type(2)". but didn't work either.

Comment: in ex2fixed i have "table-layout: fixed;" I removed that and got my table as I wanted it. But I want the table to still be fixed while having the properties in the rows specified above.
the only way I achieved that was by typing in the width property directly in the HTML code instad of the CSS. but I want it to be in my CSS

Answer (score 0):

try changing your CSS file as

```
<style>
<pre>
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:first-child{
    width: 4%;
} 

table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-child(2){
    width: 91%;
} 

table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-child(3){
    width: 5%;
} 
</pre>
</style>
```

in this, I have replaced "=" with ":" as "=" doesn't work in css and for width, when you are giving percentage you don't need to use quotes, as it doesn't work with some browsers.

Comment: thx. well I removed the class from the table. and it works now. I want the table to have the specific properties with the width (4%, 91% and 5%), but still have a "table-layout: fixed;" proportie. If I add "table-layout: fixed;" the new widths will not work...

Comment: are you trying to set width of columns of your table?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<style>
.ex2fixed tr:first-child{
    width: 4%;
} 

.ex2fixed tr:nth-child(2){
    width: 91%;
} 

.ex2fixed tr:nth-child(3){
    width: 5%;
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes you made are:

1. Using the wrong selector for a column, it's td (for columns) instead of tr (for rows)
2. as ADreNaLiNe-DJ said: the '=' isn't valid, you should use ':' to seperate key and value

Try this

```
table:nth-of-type(2) td:first-child{
    width:"4%";

} 
table:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(2){
    width:"91%";

} 
table:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(3){
    width:"5%";

}
```